# A doubt in a problem regarding Inverse function theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inverse-function-theorem

Considering the function $f(x)= \begin{cases} x+ x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x} \mbox{ if  } x \neq 0 \\
0 \mbox{ if } x=0  \end{cases},$ show that the hypothesis: $f'$ is continuous can not be removed from inverse function theorem.

I have tried in the following way:

IFT says that : If $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuously differentiable function in an open set containing $a$ and $\det f'(a)=0.$ Then there is an open set $V$ containing $a$ and an open set $W$ containing $f(a)$ such that $f: V \rightarrow W$ has a continuous inverse $f^{-1}$ which is differentiable and $(f^{-1})'(y)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(y))}$ for all $y$ in $W.$

Clearly, $f'(x)=\begin{cases} 1+2x\sin \frac{1}{x}-\cos \frac{1}{x} \mbox{ if } x \neq 0\\
1 \mbox{ if } x=0 \end{cases}.$ Now $f'(1/2 n \pi)=0$ for all $n \geq 0.$ Hence this contradict the existance of $(f^{-1})'$ near $0.$

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation of $f'(x)$ when $x\neq 0$ is incorrect.

You have differentiated a piecewise function by differentiating each piece; this is not always valid. The derivative is a limit and so its value at boundary points of the piecewise definition (here this would be $x=0$) is affected by both pieces.

More specifically: what happens to the derivative you calculated for $x\neq 0$ when you approach $0$?